# Errors compiling C code with enumerated and typedef arrays

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-errors, typedef

I can't seem to find out what is wrong with my code, which is written in C. I keep getting all kinds of errors over things that I'm almost positive aren't errors. Anyways here's the code:

```
    int  numKeyWords   =   6,
         idMaxLength   =   8,        
         maxLineLength =   80,         
         numSymbols    =   26;        
    char blankID[]    = "          "; 

    enum symbol{GREATEQ, LESSEQ, EQUAL, NOTEQ, GREAT, LESS, PLUS, MINUS, TIMES, DIVIDE,
                LBRACE, RBRACE, LPAREN, RPAREN, LBRACK, RBRACK, SEMICOLON, COMMA,
                ASSIGN, WHILE, DO, END, IF, THEN, ELSE, NUMBER, IDENT, BAD};

    enum symbol SY;
    enum symbol symbols[numKeyWords];
    enum symbol specialSymbols[UCHAR_MAX+1];

    typedef char alpha[idMaxLength+1];

    alpha idname;                        
    char chara;                          
    char line[maxLineLength];          
    int charCounter;                  
    int lineCounter;                    
    int charLineCounter;                 
    alpha keyWords[numKeyWords];          
    int isEOF = FALSE;                   

    alpha symbolNames[numSymbols];
```

I'm getting errors on specifically these lines:

```
...
enum symbol symbols[numKeyWords];
....
typedef char alpha[idMaxLength+1];
...
char line[maxLineLength];
...
alpha keyWords[numKeyWords]; 
...
alpha symbolNames[numSymbols];   
...
```

Saying something to the effect of:

error: variably modified ‘VARIABLE’ at file scope

and this is for each of the above lines. Why is this happening??

Answer (score 4):

The size of an array with static storage duration cannot be a variable; the compiler needs to be able to figure out how big it is at compile time.  Change your array size variables to `#define`s (Or `const`s if you're using C++).  (All variables at file-scope have static storage duration).

Comment: The OP specified C in the title.

Comment: @jonsca Agreed .. I felt that extra information couldn't hurt... #define is ugly style in C++

Comment: Yes, I'd much rather "have me" a `const int` any day. :)

Answer (score 1):

Put each of your int constants into a `#define` statement.  The size of a fixed length array must be known at compile time.

Comment: You cannot have variable-length arrays with static storage duration, even in C99 - this is what the OP's error message is saying.

Comment: @caf  Thank you.  I'm not familiar enough with C99, so I probably should have just forgone that whole statement in the beginning, but I was trying to be complete.  Edited now.